# Can I define a JQuery function for multiple Ids? Possible as some kind of array?

Tags: jquery

In JQuery I need to define a small function in order to do something, maybe as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickThis').click(function(e) {
        $("#showThis").doSomething();
    });
});
```

It's pretty simple, when I click on #clickThis, I want something to happen with #showThis. But now let's say I need this function not only once in a static place, but in a dynamic place like a userlist. Each of those users needs an individual `#clickThis<userid>` and then have something done with `#showThis<userid>` where `<userid>` is a generic userid.

How could I define the function properly in JQuery, so that I can use this function for all listed users? Could I maybe define IDs in some kind of array (like `<div id="clickThis[3]">` and have JQuery somehow get along with this?

Comment: That's what classes are for

Comment: could you give me an example? I'm fairly unexperienced with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using classes for your elements, and then passing the class as a query selector for the plugin.

For example:

```
<a class="myLink" href="#">a</a>
<a class="myLink" href="#">a2</a>
```

You can then use the following jQuery:

```
$('.myLink').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#showThis").doSomething();
});
```

You can also pass numerous IDs into the jQuery constructor function using commas, for example:

```
$('#id1, #id2, #etc')
```

Or you can use the [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function:

```
$('#id1').add('#id2');
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a `<ul>` element and then delegate the `click` event for dynamic `<li>` items within it. For example, consider the following markup:

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

You can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with `ul.mylist`, since `.mylist` is the closest static parent:

```
$('ul.mylist').on('click', 'li', function(e) {  
    $("#showThis").doSomething();
});
```

Using this last example is probably the best solution. It will handle `click` events on any `<li>` elements added to the DOM on the client-side (for example perhaps by jQuery or raw JavaScript).

---

If you need to access the `id` attribute inside the event handler (for example you want to access the user ID from the format `user4`, you can use:

```
<a class="myLink" id="user1" href="#">User 1</a>
<a class="myLink" id="user2" href="#">User 2</a>
<a class="myLink" id="user3" href="#">User 3</a>
```

Your jQuery would in turn look like:

```
$('.myLink').on('click', function(e) {
    var userId = this.id.replace('user', '');
});
```

This could then in turn be used to generate another selector for `doSomething()`, for example:

```
$('.myLink').on('click', function(e) {
    var userId = this.id.replace('user', '');
    $('#showThis'+userId).doSomething();
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5yA2/1/).

Comment: How would I make "a" and "a2" trigger a different showThis then? (e.g. if I click on "a" I want `$("#showThis").doSomething()`, if I click on "a2" I want `$("#showThis2").doSomething()`)

Answer (score 1):

you can add a class with each div, for example you add `class="myClass"`

```
<div id="ClickThis3" class="myClass">
<div id="ClickThis4" class="myClass">
<div id="ClickThis5" class="myClass">
```

then in jquery

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
id = id.replace("ClickThis", "");
$("#showThis"+id).doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted rather than duplicating them with a sub-standard one. -1 because IDs cannot start with non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: But now it's just a duplicate of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class on each of these elements instead of the unique ids. You can then target each of these elements using the singel class that is used by each of the elements.

But if you really want to target them using an array of elements you can use a comma:

```
$('#clickThis1, #clickThis2, etc')...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of id example:

```
$('.clickThis').click(function(){
   var idd = $(this).attr('id'); // You will get id of the element you have clicked 
});
```

Comment: Don't overdo the jQuery. `this.id` is much more efficient than `$(this).attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is dynamic, you can use attribute selector. Below is the example.

```
$( "div[id^='clickThis']" ).click(function(e) {
    var userId = $(this).attr('id');
    userId = userId.replace('clickThis','');
    $("#showThis" + userId).doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Don't overdo the jQuery. `this.id` is much more efficient than `$(this).attr('id')`.